# organize grid on ionic 3

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

how can I do to sort my grid, so .. put lines between them to differentiate an item from another item, I will show the example in HTML how I would like it to stay in ionic

**currently image on ionic**

[image]

**example of an organized grid in php / laravel**

[image]

```
ion-grid>
    <ion-row no-padding *ngFor="let dado of data" (click)="openInvoice(dado.id)">
        <ion-col col col-1  style="font-size:8px;color: #000000;background-color: ">
            {{dado.id}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col  col col-2  style="font-size:8px;color: #000000">
            {{dado.created_at}}
        </ion-col>
<ion-col  col col-2  style="font-size:8px;color: #000000">
            {{dado.name}}
        </ion-col>
<ion-col  col col-2  style="font-size:8px;color: #000000">
            {{dado.total}}
        </ion-col>
<ion-col  col col-2  style="font-size:8px;color: #000000">
            {{dado.payment_method}}
        </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `border: 1px solid grey;` to your rows/columns